# LocationMatch authentication, always allows

Tags: authentication, virtualhost

I have this in my virtual host:

```
<LocationMatch "/pressonly">
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Press Only"
     AuthUserFile /home/pur/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

It shows the login fine, but if I press cancel, I still get the page, what am I missing / doing wrong?

**Update:**

I think, after some more research I have found out that my Location / LocationMatch must go after any rewriting is performed. Therefore my vhost should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
<Location /pressonly>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Press Only"
     AuthUserFile /home/pur/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And I should not have a .htaccess file. However, using the above doesn't perform any rewriting.

Comment: Is there a `Satisfy` directive elsewhere in your config?

Comment: @ShaneMadden no I don't think so, not in the vhost or htaccess although it could be somewhere in the defaults? Any way I can check?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are still getting the page as opposed to just a caching issue from before the directory was protected? Have you tried on a freshly started browser?

Comment: @Pekka yep, I have cleared my cache in chrome, ff and IE but still happens

Comment: Are you running Linux?

Comment: @quanta sure am

Comment: Are there any `ErrorDocument 401` directives in the Apache config?

Comment: Depends on the distro, do a quick search for `Satisfy` directive with: `grep -lir satisfy /etc/httpd`, `grep -lir satisfy /var/www/html`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the order deny, allow statements as well as deny from all.  You'll also need a satisfy directive as well.  I suspect your default allow is kicking in after you cancel the authentication.

```
<Location /pressonly>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Press Only"
    AuthUserFile /home/pur/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

Update: there shouldn't be a space between allow and deny.

Comment: With those apache won't start

Comment: Thanks for the update, but still going through to the page. Will look for Satisfy entries now

Comment: I ended up getting my host admin to fix it for me. I'm not sure what they did but I know they added the ErrorDocument as @sergey vlasov said. However, seeing as you're the only one who answered - you get the bounty :)